# Router in Spring DSL not routing all the messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, router, dsl

I'm pushing in several file names to an input channel & creating an integration flow to read the names from this channel and route it to another channel based on the content of the file names.
Eg-If the file name contains 'WORD' then direct it to channel one.Here by default all the other messages (file names) should get fed to the default output channel..
However I see that.. Only one message is being fed to each channel. ie-One to the Channel one,another to the default output channel while I want all the 'not-matching-criteria' file names to be fed to the default output channel.
Any help with this using Spring DSL would be if great help.

Comment: You need to edit the question to show your configuration. Also, turning on DEBUG logging of `org.springframework.integration` and following the messages flow through the system is usually the fastest way to debug issues like this.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I guess I found out the issue. The issue was that the receiving channel was a pollable one and hence I needed to poll it continuously till it encountered a null value/timed out (PollableChannel <instance>.receive(5000)).